How to find a linear decision boundary of a linearly separable problem with unlimited class evaluations?
I have a binary classification problem, where my goal is to find a linear decision boundary (which I assume exists). The context of the problem is that I have an iterative optimization process, where I need to find a model for a constraint. This constraint yields only binary values (feasible or infeasible). In order for my algorithm to work, I need to find a linear decision boundary $\hat{g}: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$, where the hyperplane $\hat{g}(x) = 0$ corresponds to a boundary of feasibility.
In each iteration I have an initial dataset, which consists of points $\mathbf{X}^{(t)}_{1:\lambda} \in \mathbb{R}^{\lambda \times d}$ generated from a known normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(m^{(t)}, \textbf{C}^{(t)})$. I can evaluate these points on a function $g$ to obtain class labels. The particularity of this problem is that I can evaluate any number of new points $\mathbf{Y}_{1:n}$ on $g$ and obtain their class labels as well.
In order for my algorithm to work, I need to have a very precise model boundary, which would also work on the next iteration's sample which potentially has lower variance in all directions. Note that the margin of the dataset is usually very low.
Do you have any ideas on how to solve this problem?
